# Review if the query string passed to 'string SqlCommand.CommandText'

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code that contain two Methods.

The first method is for (insert, update and delete), and the second method for reading data from database.

```
//Method to insert, update and delete data from database
public async Task ExcuteCommande(string stored_procedure, SqlParameter[] param)
{
    using (SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stored_procedure))
        {
            return;
        }
        sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlcmd.CommandText = stored_procedure;
        sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconnection;
        if (param != null)
        {
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
        }
        await sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

//Method to read data from database
public async Task<DataTable> SelectData(string stored_procedure, SqlParameter[] param)
{
    using (SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stored_procedure))
        {
            return null;
        }
        sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlcmd.CommandText = stored_procedure;
        sqlcmd.Connection = sqlconnection;
        if (param != null)
        {
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddRange(param);
        }
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd))
        {
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
                await Task.Run(() => da.Fill(dt)).ConfigureAwait(false);
                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get warning and green line under this code

```
`sqlcmd.CommandText = stored_procedure;`
```

with this message:

> Warning   CA2100  Review if the query string passed to 'string SqlCommand.CommandText' in 'ExcuteCommande', accepts any user input.

What is the best way to handle this warning?

Comment: You're getting this warning because putting a string directly into a sql command is begging for a SQL injection attack. Use a parameterized query - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2100-review-sql-queries-for-security-vulnerabilities?view=vs-2019

Comment: Yes I see this document but unfortunately does not help me ,Actually this code from data access layer and the 'stored_procedure' is the name of Stored Procedure this example of how i use it                                                          public async Task<DataTable> GetCustomer()
        {
            DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = await DAL.SelectData("GetCustomer", null);
            DAL.Close();
            return dt;

        }

Comment: If you know that the input is safe and is not user input then you can suppress the warning with `pragma warning disable CA2100` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-pragma-warning